# Функция cbind в R

Tags: r

Функции cbind  и rbind. Как убрать кавычки значений получившейся датафрейма? Например:

```
my.vector<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
my.vector2<-c("window","door","floor","door","floor")
my.vector3<-c(6:10)
cbind(my.vector,my.vector2,my.vector3)
     my.vector my.vector2 my.vector3

[1,] "1"       "window"   "6"       
[2,] "2"       "door"     "7"       
[3,] "3"       "floor"    "8"       
[4,] "4"       "door"     "9"       
[5,] "5"       "floor"    "10"
```

есть ли способ избавиться от кавычек?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

`cbind` возвращает объект класса `matrix`, а в матрице могут быть только значения одного типа. В данном случае один из исходных векторов содержит строки, поэтому все приводится к типу `character`. Поменять тип столбца можно обычным способом:

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(my.vector,my.vector2,my.vector3))
df[[1]] <- as.numeric(df[[1]])
str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ my.vector : num  1 2 3 4 5
 $ my.vector2: Factor w/ 3 levels "door","floor",..: 3 1 2 1 2
 $ my.vector3: Factor w/ 5 levels "10","6","7","8",..: 2 3 4 5 1
```

Или же нужно сразу создавать таблицу с помощью `data.frame()`.

Например :

```
data.frame(my.vector,my.vector2,my.vector3)
  my.vector my.vector2 my.vector3
1         1     window          6
2         2       door          7
3         3      floor          8
4         4       door          9
5         5      floor         10
```

Comment: спасибо! но почему мы меняем тип 1-го столбца, если необходимо поменять 2-ой?

Comment: В смысле - поменять второй? Там фактор, который разве что можно сделать обычным символьным вектором (`as.character(df[[2]])`). А чисто визуально кавычек не будет, если вывести в консоль непосредственно таблицу `as.data.frame(cbind(my.vector,my.vector2,my.vector3))`.